# How to add a specific widget to only 1 page?

Tags: pages, widgets, screen-layout

I would like to show a widget in only one page of my site, as i can see it is not possible right?

Should i add that for all my site pages or not?

Comment: It's possible. The easiest way is to use a plugin such as http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/

Comment: Is this a custom theme or a custom widget?

Comment: custom theme, FashionStyle from SMthemes dot com

Comment: [Widget Display Options](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-display-options/) Another Plugin that does this

Comment: Here's a better solution which works with any theme and is easy to customize http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127111/display-custom-homepage-text-based-on-domain/128354#128354

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on where you want to show the widget.

Let’s start with the widget area (sidebar) registration:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_76959_register_widget_area' );
function wpse_76959_register_widget_area()
{
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => __(
                'Widgets on page Sample Page',
                'theme_textdomain'
                ),
            'description'   => __(
                'Will be used on a page with a slug "sample-page" only.',
                'theme_textdomain'
                ),
            'id'            => 'sample-only',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="sample-only-widget">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2>',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );
}
```

This is quite simple. We register a new widget area with some custom markup.

> [image]

Now we have to show it somewhere. We could add a custom action in our `page.php` template:

```
do_action( 'show_sample_widget' );
```

Or we could use an existing action, this would limit the places where the widget is available. For example the action `loop_start` is called the first time we call `the_post()` in a loop. If we want to set the widget on top of the page content, we use that hook:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_76959_render_widget' );

function wpse_76959_render_widget()
{
    is_page( 'sample-page' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'sample-only' );
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
}
```

For a custom action we’d use instead:

```
add_action( 'show_sample_widget', 'wpse_76959_render_widget' );
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several plugins that allow to show widgets based on specific conditions:

- [Display Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/): Clean and simple interface
- [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/): It has a few more options than the previous one
- [Dynamic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/): This is the most rich of features
- [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/): This is aimed to programmers as you need to write the condition in PHP code. I.e. `is_page('about')`

An alternative solution is given by the following plugin, which allows you to define a custom set of widgets on a per-page basis, directly from the edit page screen:

- [WP Page Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-page-widget/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable editing the templates files for your theme:

Find where

```
dynamic_sidebar('side_bar_name');
```

is called, and either before or after it, or prettymuch anywhere on your site use:

```
$pageTitle =  get_the_title($post->ID); 
$targetPage = 'the title of the page you want to target goes here';

    if($pageTitle == $targetTitle){    
     the_widget( 'the_widget_unique_id_aka_name', $instance, $args);
    }
   //the_widget() calls a specific widget and displays it
```

If you want to be cleaner about it: Create a function in functions.php that would look like:

```
function call_my_widget( $post ){
    $pageTitle =  get_the_title($post-ID); 
    $targetPage = 'the title of the page you want to target goes here';

        if($pageTitle == $targetTitle){    
         the_widget( 'the_widget_unique_id_aka_name', $instance, $args);
        }
}
```

call the function with:

```
call_my_widget( $post );
```

this has to be called in the loop or where the `$post` global variable is existant.

Then call that function in your template file (page.php perhaps?) to display your target widgets on only your target page.

Comment: what is `$instance` here..?

Comment: From the [WP Docs:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) $instance (array|string) (optional) The widget's instance settings. Either an array or query-style string. See each widget below for examples. In my case it was a empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `widget_display_callback` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_display_callback/ and just change the page id on the code below.

```
function custom_display_callback( $instance, $widget, $args ){
    if( is_page( 10 ) ){
        return false;
    }
    return $instance;
}
add_filter( 'widget_display_callback', 'custom_display_callback', 50, 3 );
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!